# Query against subquery yields different results than running subquery alone

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that uses a subquery to subset the data, then I'm trying to select specific data from the subquery. The subquery is:

```
select top 10 Build_ID, Appscan_Definitive_High,
rank() over (order by Appscan_Definitive_High desc) as rankpct
from 
(
select build_id, convert(int,appscan_definitive_high) as
           appscan_definitive_high
from dbo.SDFBuildMetrics
where coalesce(appscan_definitive_high,0)>0
) a
```

and the results from this are:

```
Build_ID    Appscan_Definitive_High rankpct
31966   51  1
32627   51  1
44293   51  1
47011   51  1
47968   51  1
48554   51  1
25586   49  7
27370   49  7
40357   48  9
23867   44  10
```

But when I run a query against the subquery:

```
select Appscan_Definitive_High
from
(
select top 10 Build_ID, Appscan_Definitive_High,
    rank() over (order by Appscan_Definitive_High desc) as rankpct
from 
(
    select build_id, convert(int,appscan_definitive_high) as
                appscan_definitive_high
    from dbo.SDFBuildMetrics
    where coalesce(appscan_definitive_high,0)>0
) a 
 ) aa
```

I get:

```
Appscan_Definitive_High
1
44
21
44
2
44
2
6
7
7
```

The ultimate intent of the full query is to retrieve min(AppScan_Definitive_High) but since the set of values being returned doesn't match the set of values returned from the subquery the min function doesn't give me what I need. I assume the subquery returns a set of data that the outer query operates against, but this appears to not be the case in the above example.

Any help with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're running select top 10 without order by. To get the result you want you need to have order by there.

Comment: Huh. a) I didn't think you could specify order by on a subquery and b) I'm not sure I understand why that would matter. If the subquery returns a set of data as shown in the first example is that what the outer query operates on? It works, but I'm not entirely sure why...

Comment: You can (and probably should) always specify order by with top. If you don't SQL Server can skip thing or for example parallelism can cause different kind of results. Actual execution plan might reveal why this happened.